# Add Choices in a numericFilter in django-filter

Tags: django, django-filter

this is my filter

```
class RiderFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    cost_gt = django_filters.NumberFilter(label='Costo maggiore di',lookup_expr='cost__gt')
    cost_lt = django_filters.NumberFilter(label='Costo minore di',lookup_expr='cost__lt')
    class Meta:
        model = Rider
        fields = [ ]
```

how can i add some specific choice to my cost_gt and cost_lt?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a `ChoiceFilter`.

```py
class RiderFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    cost_gt = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(
        label='Costo maggiore di',
        field_name='cost', lookup_expr='gt', 
        choices=[(1, '1'), (2, '2'), (3, '3')],
    )
    cost_lt = django_filters.NumberFilter(
        label='Costo minore di',
         field_name='cost', lookup_expr='lt', 
         choices=[(4, '4'), (5, '5'), (6, '6')],
    )
```